# How do I get Rails variables from my returned jQuery Ajax data?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I have an Ajax request from a page in my Rails app that looks like so:

```
$.ajax({
 type: 'POST',
 url: '/users/create/',
 data: "screen_name=<%=@user.screen_name%>",
 success: createSuccessHandler,
 error: createErrorHandler,
 complete: hideLoadingImage
});
```

And currently the action responds with this:

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.js  { render :text => @user}
  format.html { redirect_to @user }
end
```

**The create action works fine but how to I get the returned values (data) in my success method so I can do something like this?**

```
function createSuccessHandler(data) {

    $("#div1").append(data.value1); 
    $("#div2").append(data.value2); 

}
```

Basically I'm trying to split the data up into different variables.

Comment: did you try to work with render :text => @user.to_json?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Return json in your controller (e.g., add a `format.json` stanza and request that instead of the .js one).  Then in your `createSuccessHandler` function you'll do something like:

```
var foo = eval(data);
$("#div1").append(foo.value1); 
$("#div2").append(foo.value2);
```

Note that some javascript libraries (like jQuery) provide safer ways to handle json than using `eval`, feel free to use those instead.